# Error en login con angular

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express

he estado viendo como hacer un login y un register con el stack MEAN, el register me funciona perfectamente, pero el login no, no entiendo el error, porque me manda un codigo de estatus 200, es decir, que el email y la contraseña son correctos y a la vez me dice que hay un error y no me deja pasar a la siguiente ruta.

Esto es lo que muestra cuando hago las peticiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi componente

```
Componente signIn

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service'
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  user={
  }
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  signIn(){
    this.authService.signIn(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          console.log(res)
        },
        err=>console.log(err)
      );
  }

}
```

El servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

   signUp(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL+'/signup',user)
   }

   signIn(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.URL+'/signin',user)
   }
}
```

Con este funcion verifico el Token, se supone que cada vez que hago un login se crea un token.

```
function verificarToken(req,res,next){
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        return res.status(401).send("Peticion no autorizada")
    }

    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    if(token=='null'){
        return res.status(401).send("Peticion no autorizada")
    }

    let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey')
    req.userId = payload._id;
    next();
}
```

Comment: Ahora lo he modificado y resulta que ahora no encuentra ningun correo, ahora el error es 401 :/

Comment: como devuelves la respuesta desde mongodb cuando el login es correcto? Es decir, la respuesta es de tipo json o text u otro?